# Windows Store account and Windows Phone Store account

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-store-apps

A week back I purchased dev account to deploy my windows phone app.
But while testing on my mobile I am getting device is not registered. When I reviewed my billing info, it says
**Item(s)
Developer services
- Windows Store developer account annual registration**  that has been purchased..

Is this not the correct account which I should have bought? 
Windows phone account is different from windows store account ? What should I do now?

Answer (score 4):

Windows Store account is meant for the Windows 8 (Tablet/PC) application developement. And that is different from Windows Phone account.

Check [Windows Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/) and [Windows Phone Store](http://dev.windowsphone.com/) for more details

Comment: Though the documentation states there are no refunds, Microsoft often will if you submit a support request. The downside is you'll have to register with a new name/company.